# How to check if point is in line shadow

Tags: math, geometry, vector-graphics

I can't really figure out how exactly to phrase this question, so I made a crude graphic explaining what I'm trying to ask: [image]

Given a line comprised of two points, how would I go about checking if a given point was within the area relative to the line as displayed in the image? Sorry if there is a term for this that I didn't know.

Comment: As a side note-- this question is probably off-topic for stackoverflow :).

Comment: I thought it may be, but due to the fact that I need this explained to me in terms of programming concepts I thought it was fair game here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your line segment points are `p1` and `p2`, and your query point is `q`:

1. Compute the line segment length `b := |p2 - p1|` and line direction (normalized) `z := (p2 - p1) / b` and
2. Compute the vector from `p1` to `q`, defined as `w := (q - p1)`.
3. Project the query point onto the infinite line by computing `q' := w dot z`. This gives you the position of the point as if it moved to the line via an orthogonal path from its original position.
4. Inspect `q`: If `q > b` then your query point is outside of the line segment shadow, past `p2`. If `q < 0` then your query point is outside of the line segment shadow, past `p1`. Otherwise, `q` is "inside".

Comment: Thank you, this was very easy to follow. Is [this code](http://pastebin.com/UWFPqF4g) a correct implementation of this? Excuse the added complications of the graphical lib I use.

EDIT: Save for the fact that I need to use the vector distance formula for line 5, which I am adding to my code now

Answer (score 0):

Base point A, base point B, lines AB, AD and BE (where DE is parallel to AB and further from AB than C. If CA or CB intersects AD or BE, then C is outside the target area. If neither CA nor CB intersect AD or BE, then C is inside the target area. And if both CA and CB intersect AD and BE, then C is on either AD or BE.

In your left example, ABC is a triangle that does not intersect AD or BE. In your right example, ABC is a triangle, and CB intersects AD.

Have fun coding that!